# Arthmetic operation in structure

Tags: c, structure

Is something like this is possible in C language:

```
typedef struct S {
    char a;
    int b;
    int c = this.a * 60 + this.b;
} S;
```

Such type of structure will be very usefull in my code.

Answer (score 3):

No, in `C` you can't assign remember value  in declaration, it would be compilation time error.

But one solution I can suggest(may be you like):

```
#define INIT(this, a, b)  {a, b, (this).a * 60 + (this).b}
```

and call it:

```
S s = INIT(s, '5', 6);
```

Comment: the call to your defined macro has a typo

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can make a factory function that does the initialization for you:

```
// With a name like alloc, it's clear that the 
// user is responsible for freeing the memory allocated.
S* alloc_s(char a, int b) {
    S* s = malloc(sizeof(S));
    s->a = a;
    s->b = b;
    s->c = s->a * 60 + s->b;
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in C (or even in GNU C). You cannot have default values for structure object members.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. It will trigger errors upon compilation. However if you want c to have a certain value you can do:
`static const int c = 666;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the expression without knowing the a and b first.
You could simulate the class like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S;

typedef  struct S {
    char a;
    int b;
    int (*getC)(struct S* sss);
} S;

int getC(S* sss) { return sss->a*60+sss->b; }

S* make_S()
{
    S* p = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));
    if(p==NULL) return NULL;
    p->getC = &getC;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    S* s1 = make_S();

    s1->a = 1;
    s1->b = 2;
    printf("%i\n", s1->getC(s1));
    free(s1);
    return 0;
}
```